# Is it possible to release a project under the GPL if it contains MIT-licensed libraries?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, mit

Specifically the Symfony PHP framework, which is MIT licensed. I've read that the two are compatible, but I want to make sure that a system I develop can be released complete under the GPL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to release a project that uses MIT licensed libraries under a GPL license. The MIT license is a *permissive* license which has <s>no</s> very few restrictions on code that links to its binaries.

Incidentally, you could also include actual MIT licensed *source code* in a GPL project. It's very developer friendly that way.

However, this is a one way compatability. You cannot do this the other way around and include GPL code in an MIT project because the GPL requires code that links to it also be licensed GPL. Once you let any GPL code or libraries into your project, you must license the whole project under the GPL.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so but I wanted to be über sure!

Comment: You're welcome @Mrshll1001, but on a personal note, I would encourage you to extend the same courtesy to the people who end up building on top of your work and not use the GPL...

Comment: It's worth clarifying that the code isn't really _relicensed_ in this case, although we often talk about it that way. The original terms of the MIT license still apply. They just happen to be liberal enough that they don't interfere with distributing the whole under the GPL.